# Automator: Picking items from a list using characters in name and performing a "find" showing only the results

Tags: automator

I regularly make folders filled with lots of items that contain multiple versions of specific files. We often need to view them in very specific ways by version number.

i.e.:

- file_v01.jpg
- file_v02.jpg
- file_v03.jpg
- file_v04.jpg
- file_v05.jpg
- file_v06.jpg
- file2_v01.jpg
- file2_v02.jpg
- file2_v03.jpg
- file2_v04.jpg
- file2_v05.jpg
- file2_v06.jpg
- file3_v01.jpg
- file3_v02.jpg
- file3_v03.jpg
- file3_v04.jpg
- file3_v05.jpg
- file3_v06.jpg
- file4_v01.jpg
- file4_v02.jpg
- file4_v03.jpg
- file4_v04.jpg
- file4_v05.jpg
- file4_v06.jpg

I'd like to be able to make an Automator script/action/whatever that will work the same way as performing a search *just in that folder* and that will narrow the results per the item searched. Then that automator script would live as a button at the top of my Finder window (using the "Customize Toolbar" feature to add them one at a time).

So...

The user has a folder with 80 files in it, all named with the convention like those above. The user clicks the little button called "v01" and then they are only viewing the files that contain "v01" in the filename *only* in that folder.

I'd make automator items for "v02" and "v03" etc., having multiple buttons in the top bar, all the way up to v07. Then the user can click them to see all the "v02" items, or "v03" items.

I have never used Automator, so I have no idea where to start. I am NOT a coder.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not just use the built-in search on the folder for filenames that contain the qualifier?

Comment: I want to make it easier for our team with a simple button click. (It will also give me a chance to get my feet wet using Automator)